# googleアナリティクスのようなトラッキングタグがありますが、あれがどのような原理で動いているのかがわかりません。

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?hl=ja

ユーザーが埋め込んでもらうスクリプトタグの中で、google-analytics.com/analytics.jsにアクセスし、それを元に、ログを収集するようなスクリプトが発火しているのかなという漠然な理解をしておりますが、google-analytics.com/analytics.jsのスクリプト内容を見ても、全然理解ができず、仕組みがわかりません。

そこで以下質問です。

・analytics.jsの処理の中で、どのようにして、ユーザーのIPアドレスなどを収集してデータをGoogle側が保存しているのでしょうか？（ここが一番よくわかりません、どのようにして、いろいろなデータを抜いているのだろうといつも疑問に思ってます。）

・ユーザーは不特定多数野中、cross origin問題にひっかからないようにすることは簡単にできるのでしょうか？

・サーバー上にgoogle-analytics.com/analytics.jsのようなjsファイルを設置し、ユーザーが設置したスクリプトファイルを元にそこにアクセスをする。のだと思いますが、以下の処理でそれをしているのでしょうか？

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

window.document.writeという関数はありますが、window.document.scriptというのはgoogleが独自に作った関数なのでしょうか？

以上、何卒宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

それこそググってみましょう...。Googleの解説を読んでください。
リンクだけ載せるのはルール違反ですが、一言でまとめられる話ではないので。

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview?hl=ja

ポイントはデータ収集後、その情報を載せたURLのタグをDOMに押し込んで1ピクセルのGIFをロードするところにあります。画像なのでoriginの問題はありません。

Answer (score -3):

以前、＠ITにGoogle Analyticsの解説記事が出ていました（下記リンク）
参考になると思います。

[Googleアナリティクス入門：第1回　IT管理者も知っておきたいGoogleアナリティクスの概要](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1504/23/news023.html)

Comment: ざっと読みましたが、その記事に技術的な解説は書かれていないように思うのですが…